# show result which is created through JavaScript in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in which a date/time picker is working fine.

I created JavaScript to calculate the two fields' date difference and show in a third field - named **Course Duration**.

Somehow I am not able to display the results in the "Course Duration" input Field.

Code:

```js
function GetDays() {
  var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("course_end_date").value);
  var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("admission_date").value);
  return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal() {
  if (document.getElementById("course_end_date")) {
    document.getElementById("course_duration").value = GetDays();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="admission_date" name="admission_date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
<input id="course_end_date" name="course_end_date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
<input id="course_duration" name="course_duration" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
```

Comment: Do you actually call the function cal()?

Comment: Bro Seriously Says I Don't Know How to Call Function in Input Filed

Comment: what does "not able to" mean exactly? What is going wrong in your code when you run it? What are you stuck on? Is there something specific you don't understand? It's not clear. From what I can see, it would probably work except that you are never calling the `cal()` function. Is there a button which triggers this function, perhaps? Did you miss that out from your example? Please include all relevant code and give a clear description of the actual specific problem you are experiencing. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. In English you do not put a capital letter at the beginning of a word except if it is the name of a person or a place, or it is at the start of a sentences. And sentences are always ended by full stops. I edited your original post because it was unreadable. You put too many capitals, and you did not end any of your sentences.

Comment: @MoviesDhamaka in your code somewhere, you need to call your `cal()` function, so your code can run

Comment: i used on <input id="course_duration" name="course_duration" placeholder="" type="text"  onchange="cal()" class="form-control" value="" />

Comment: I would like to say that putting the "onchange" on the course_duration field does not make any sense, because the user is not trying to change that field - **you** are trying to change that field with your code. So I think the function will never be executed because the user is never likely to type in that box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something to trigger the `cal()` function, which currently you don't have.

So I made a demo below which has a "Calculate" button. Enter your dates and then press the button, and it will run the calculation. As long as you enter valid dates, it should work.

For example, if you enter `2018-02-01` and `2018-02-02` it will return `366`.

```js
var calcButton = document.getElementById("calculate");
calcButton.addEventListener("click", cal);

function GetDays() {
  var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("course_end_date").value);
  var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("admission_date").value);
  return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal() {
  if (document.getElementById("course_end_date")) {
    document.getElementById("course_duration").value = GetDays();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="admission_date" name="admission_date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
<input id="course_end_date" name="course_end_date" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
<button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>
<input id="course_duration" name="course_duration" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Adyson Its Works For Me However I Was Looking for When Someone Sect Dates in Two Input Fields the Difference will Display Automatically in the Third Field But This is Very Help Ful For Me

Comment: Well for that you could add an "onchange" event to the "course_end_date" field, if you like. P.S. You don't have to put a capital letter in front of every word. Only names and the first word in each sentence need a capital letter :-)

Comment: onchange="cal()" is working best for me and it started giving me accurate value how can i add string or word like days or No. of days

Comment: Just put "No of days" as text before the `<input id="course_duration"` i.e. `<button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>No. of days<input id="course_duration" name="course_duration" placeholder="" type="text" class="form-control" value="" />` . Don't try to make it inside the input because that should contain the value only, not the description.

Comment: Thanks ADyson Works Cool